# Redirecting all the links from HTTPS to HTTP WordPress website

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a WordPress website and i need to redirect all the HTTPS links of my website to HTTP so there will be no HTTPS links for the website. For example (redirecting https://www.example.com to http://www.example.com) I have tried myself and add the following code in my .htaccess file in the website directory to redirect all https links to http.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But still the website https links are not redirected to http. Can you please help me out how to redirect and where i am wrong in my code??

Answer (score 0):

There are some specific cases when you want to redirect particular URL or a single website to be opened through HTTP instead of HTTPS. For that purpose you should add the following rewrite rule in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Detailed reference: [URL](https://wp-mix.com/htaccess-redirect-http-to-https/)